# Using SSH.NET on C# Console application in Visual Studio 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, ssh.net, net-sftp

I have a Visual Studio 2008 project in C# with .NET Framework 3.5 and I would like to use [SSH.NET](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/625304) library but I see no binaries there for last stable release 2016.0.0.

Also in home page says it has been moved to [here](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET). Once I go to this page, I see three branches, develop, master and sftpfilestream, so which one I have to take which is compatible with .NET Framework 3.5 (My project uses .NET Framework 3.5 on Visual Studio 2008)?

Also If I downloaded any of them, once unzipped I do not see any DLL, only projects. Well, in fact, I prefer to reference a project within mine in order to use it, but by curiosity, where are the binaries (DLLs)? and which project is the correct I have to add to mine for .NET Framework 3.5?